# jquery cycle2 trigger next when html5 video has ended

Tags: jquery, html, video, slideshow

I am using the cycle2 plugin in jquery to make a video slideshow. I currently have the following code that will display the videos.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
 $('video')[0].play();
 $('#cycle-2').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl,  incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
    $('video', outgoingSlideEl)[0].pause();
});
$('#cycle-2').on('cycle-before',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl,     incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
     $('video', incomingSlideEl)[0].play();
});

});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="cycle-2" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle timeout="16000"

    data-cycle-fx="fade"

data-cycle-log="false"

data-cycle-loop="-1"
    data-cycle-allow-wrap="false">
    <div><video class="vid"><source src="media/vid1.webm" type="video/webm"></video></div>
    <div><video class="vid"><source src="media/vid2.webm" type="video/webm"></video></div>
    <div><video class="vid"><source src="media/vid3.webm" type="video/webm"></video></div>

</body>
```

It works on a timeout of 16 seconds, which is the length of the first video, but I would like to to trigger the next slide when the current video has finished playing.

I know html5 has an event

```
    $('video.my-video').bind('ended', function(){
      // make some stuff
});
```

but I am unsure where to put it to trigger the next event

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this anywhere in your JavaScript `<script>` block:

```
$(document).on('ended', 'video.vid', function(){
    $(this).closest('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next'); // trigger next slide
});
```

Comment: Although your script did not work out of the box, I managed to alter it so that it worked with my script. -                 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    //Blazemonger addition to script- with adjustments
     $(function(){
     $('video').on('ended',  function(){
         $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next'); // trigger next slide
     });
    // addition end

     $('video')[0].play();